# Fetching multiple row columns different values into single row based on a criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables
Files,
FileTypes

Files will hold the data of both files types internal and external for all clients
i want to fetch a client's file in a single row with internal file path and extenral filepath.

Below is the metadata

```
create table filetypes (
  filetypeid int  primary key,
  typename varchar(20)
);

create table files (
  fileid int  primary key,
  filetypeid int,
  fiilepath nvarchar(200),
  client_id int
);

insert into files values (10, 1,'\testpath9\\InternalFoldername', 1);
insert into files values (11, 2,'\testpath2\\ExternalFoldername', 1);
insert into files values (12, 1,'\testpath5\\InternalFoldername', 2);
insert into files values (13, 2,'\testpath6\\ExternalFoldername', 3);


insert into filetypes values (1,'Internal');
insert into filetypes values (2,'External');
```

i want to have SQL to fetch results like below

```
client_id   InternalPath                   ExternalPath
----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
1           \testpath9\\InternalFoldername \testpath2\\ExternalFoldername
```

Comment: what if you have 3 filetypes? do you want to have 3 columns? Try using pivot, it may help

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql statement,

```
 select  t1.internal_client as client_id, t1.InternalPath as InternalPath, 
 t2.ExternalPath as ExternalPath from 
 (select  client_id  as internal_client,fiilepath as InternalPath from files where filetypeid=1 ) t1 
 left join
 (select  client_id as external_client, fiilepath  as ExternalPath from files where filetypeid=2 )t2
 on t1.internal_client = t2.external_client 
 where t1.InternalPath IS NOT NULL and t2.ExternalPath IS NOT NULL
```